# Processing JS Hit Box Not Working

Tags: processing.js

I am trying to make a hit box that causes a program restart when triggered.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 if(snakey.position.x < mos.position.x + 20 && snakey.position.y > mos.position.y - 20 || snakey.position.x > mos.position.x - 20 && snakey.position.y < mos.position.y + 20){
        Program.restart();
    }
```

The problem is that instead of triggering the program restart when the hit box is entered it seems to be triggering randomly or at least very erratically. I have checked this several times and am getting no error messages so the syntax is fine.

Me and a friend have also both gone over the logic several times to make sure that the conditions can actually be met. We have found no problems, but it is still not activating the program restart at the right time or even at a consistent time I will link the full program bellow if anyone can tell me why it is acting so strange I would appreciate it.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-project-computational-creatures/5001415574814720

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the conditions in brackets properly
`if((snakey.position.x < mos.position.x + 20 && snakey.position.y > mos.position.y - 20) || (snakey.position.x > mos.position.x - 20 && snakey.position.y < mos.position.y + 20))`

Comment: That syntax is only for normal JS this is Processing JS if I put it that way I get a message about incorrect syntax. Also are you sure that improper syntax could even cause the type of problem I described wouldn´t it just cause those lines not to run?

Comment: your syntax is valid but you have a logical error in you statement that's why randomness

Comment: Ok I figured there must be a logical error but like I said I have read it and a friend of mine has read it multiple times and we do not see the logical problem that is why I brought it here to see if anyone could find the wrong logic. Do you see a specific error?

Comment: NVM found it on my own.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: There was an || were there should have been an && and two of the coordinates were in the wrong place.